# Dynamically building object in the loop from another array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I want to build an object dynamically from array inside another object. I have put together my code below but that code is fetching the data and building static object.

```js
const data = {
    "time": {
        "bkts": [
            {
                "timex": "2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "bkts": [
                    {
                        "key": "abc",
                        "trd1": {
                            "value": 0.2
                        },
                        "trd2": {
                            "value": 1.2
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "timex": "2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "bkts": [
                    {
                        "key": "xyz",
                        "trd1": {
                            "value": 0.2
                        },
                        "trd2": {
                            "value": 1.2
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};

let timestamp = "";
let trd1 = "";
let trd2 = "";
let trdArray1 = [];
let trdArray2 = [];
let dataArray = [];
const responseData = data.time;
responseData.bkts.map(function (val) {
    timestamp = new Date(val.timex);
    val.bkts.map((sub_val) => {
        trd1 = sub_val.trd1.value;
        trd2 = sub_val.trd2.value;
    });
    trdArray1.push([timestamp,trd1]);          
    trdArray2.push([timestamp,trd2]);   
    const trd1Object = {
        id: "trd1",
        name: "Trd 1",
        data: trdArray1
    };
    const trd2Object = {
        id: "trd2",
        name: "Trd 2",
        data: trdArray2
    };
    const trd1ObjectArray = new Array(trd1Object);
    const trd2ObjectArray = new Array(trd2Object);
    dataArray = [...trd1ObjectArray,...trd2ObjectArray];
});
console.log(dataArray);
```

The above code works fine but I want it to be dynamic so if there are 10 numbers of items "trd" then i dont need to build my code 10 times.

Comment: Your code has a number of syntax errors - it doesn't actually work fine. Can you fix them so that it runs properly?

Comment: To be more specific, your data is missing commas after each date and your array push statements are missing brackets. There appear to be other minor errors too.

Comment: Your input is badly formatted. If at all possible, change whatever's generating that code so that the `trd`s are in the shape of an array instead of ascending numeric string indicies `trd1`, `trd2`, etc.

Comment: I have updated the code and it is not giving syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I think there is many things to focus on here,
The first thing, your code contains many many syntax errors, some missing commas and closing brackets, so run anywhere and track these errors first until you reach to the error that says `Uncaught TypeError: trd1Object is not iterable` and then let's talk.

**The first point**:

You cannot spread an object inside an array, only the opposite is possible.

---

**The second point:**

You don't need to use the `map()` method to loop over the array, the `map()` method is created to return a new updated array from an existing one, and not to loop over an array to just do some actions.

You can use the `forEach()` method for this porpuse, and it's the same syntax.

---

**The third point:**

You have a problem in declaring variables, which is declaring multiple variables in the same line and assign a value for them all.

This just assigns the value to the last variable, and the first ones will be `undefined`
which means, if you have this line of code:

```
let x, y, z = ""
```

then you find that `x = undefined` and `y = undefined` and `z = ""` so you cannot use this syntax here, I know that it's found in some other languages but not in javascript.

---

**The fourth point:**

If you need to build a dynamic code, you must put all the variables *except the parent array* inside the `function` of the `map()` or the `forEach()` method, which means that every time the function will be called, these variables will be created newly just for this new value, and then append the final result of your function to the parent array.

---

I could help you with more examples of code snippets if I understood exactly what you need to do, and If the code works well.

And a small advice, when working on anything even for training, name your variables with the full meaning of it, and name everything with a descriptive names, because nobody understands what variables means here.